# Wrap legacy AsyncTask by an Observable Rxjava?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, rx-java

I have to use a legacy library that using AsyncTask for a background job. How I can wrap an AsyncTask by an Observable object which I'm using on my current project.

The AsyncTask is encapsulated so I cannot access the synchronous call inside AsyncTask.

Comment: sorry to ask, how you try to implement that ?

Comment: How do you call that library? If that library has any Synchronous calling function then you can easily convert it to Observable object.

Comment: Thanks for your questions. The library provides an AsyncTask and require a listener for handling the callback. 
Synchronous call is inside the AsyncTask so I cannot access to create an observable from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

say you have an object *asynchronousCall* executing some async work with *call()* method which takes callback as a param, you can wrap it like that :

```
    Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super Object> subscriber) {
            asynchronousCall.call(new CallBack() {
                @Override
                public void success(Object o) {
                    subscriber.onNext(o);
                    subscriber.onCompleted();
                }

                @Override
                public void error(Throwable t) {
                    subscriber.onError(t);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just updated my question with more details: The AsyncTask is encapsulated so I cannot access the synchronous call inside AsyncTask.

Thanks

Comment: in this example asynchronousCall.call() is also asynchronous, that's why it take callback as a param, can you provide a short example how you use that api now?

Comment: Thank you so much. You've made my day. Sorry for didn't read your answer carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to the case when you cannot or don't want to wrap execution in an `Observable` is to use [`Subjects`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Subject<Object, Object> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    Listener listener = new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void onCallback(Object object) {
            subject.onNext(object);
            subject.onCompleted();
        }
    };
    subject.subscribe(object -> yourReaction(object));
    someMethodWithCallback(listener);
}

public interface Listener {

    void onCallback(Object object);

}
```

`Subject` being an `Observer` allows you to send items into it, while it being an `Observable` allows you to subscribe to it and receive these events.